# Gremlin Client Connecting to Gremlin / JanusGraph Server via URL-based Load Balancers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlinpython, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

Due to security policies, I have a cluster of JanusGraph servers (running in an internal Kubernetes network) that can be accessed by external Gremlin clients via the below network route:

clients --> global load balancer ([URL-based](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#websocket_proxy_support)) --> third-party firewall --> internal load balancer --> graph servers

The endpoint exposed by the global load balancer is something like e.g. https://myhost.com/mypath1/mypath2/

This approach works fine for HTTP(S) based requests, as I am able to receive a response from the gremlin server when firing a `curl` command to the above global load balancer endpoint.

However, I have 2 other gremlin client usage patterns:

1. using `gremlin.sh` console
2. using `gremlin-python` client (or more generally, WebSocket clients)

Hence my questions are:

1. In the `remote.yaml` file used by `gremlin.sh` client, how do I specify the global load balancer endpoint in the `hosts` and `port` parameters?

   - I have tried a few combinations (e.g. `hosts` = ['myhost.com']/['myhost.com/mypath1/mypath2'], `port` = 8182/443) but they all don't work
2. In `gremlin-python` client, I am using a WebSocket-based connection. How do I specify the websocket connection string with the above endpoint?

   - I have tried various connection strings (e.g. `ws(s)://myhost.com/mypath1/mypath2/gremlin`) but they don't work too

Answer (score 1):

> In the remote.yaml file used by gremlin.sh client, how do I specify the global load balancer endpoint in the hosts and port parameters?

For `hosts` you should just supply the host name (no path) and for port, it should just be 443 assuming that is the port you've exposed on your load balancer. Of course you also need to enable SSL - as [an example](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.4.6/gremlin-console/conf/remote-secure.yaml#L32-L33) note the settings provided in the packaged `remote-secure.yaml` file and see additional configuration options in `https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuration`.

As for your custom path of `mypath1/mypath2/gremlin`, that is not configurable at this time. It expects that path to be `/gremlin`. I've created [TINKERPOP-2379](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2379) in response.

> In gremlin-python client, I am using a WebSocket-based connection. How do I specify the websocket connection string with the above endpoint?

I would expect this to work for Python: `wss://myhost.com:443/mypath1/mypath2/gremlin`

Comment: Thanks! For the python WebSocket connection string I am facing `HTTPError: HTTP 599: Timeout during request` error. But I will need to check internally if the load balancer supports WebSocket connections.